# mongodb - php - match and group error in aggregate

Tags: php, mongodb

My mongodb aggregate function works fine, but my PHP doesn't.

This is my PHP code and mongodb script respectively :

**php:**

```
$group_by_app = [['$match' => ['Name' => 'Tom']],['$group' => ['_id' => '$Hobbit', 'count' => ['$sum' => 1]]]];

$cursor = $collection -> aggregate($group_by_app);
```

**mongodb script :**

```
db.myCollocations.aggregate({$match:{Name:'Tom'}},{$group:{_id:"$Hobbit",count:{"$sum":1}}})
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Btw my mongodb php driver version is 1.5.8.

And I've replace the **aggregate** function to **aggregateCursor** and **it work then.**

So the problem is solved I think.

Answer (score 0):

I've replaced the `aggregate` function with `aggregateCursor` and it works. So it appears that the problem is resolved.